# Automaticly deploy app from jenkins over Wifi

Tags: android, jenkins, xamarin, continuous-deployment

I’m doing research on CI integration of android xamrin application. I have found how to build app and make apk using Jenkins but I can’t find a way to send application to devices that are available in company network to automatically update app on those devices. The best option would be to close app, update it and run again o users are not required to do nothing.

Comment: You could use HockeyApp for this. The SDK provides and Update Manager, which you could use for a group only for internal devices.

Comment: You will need to use some third party service for this, like HockeyApp or Google Play beta or something. You can't simply push out APK's over the network directly to people's phones (unless you do some custom prep on the receiver phones), at least it seems very unlikely from a security perspective.

Comment: HockeyApp looks good for me - Thanks